# Equilibrium point rumor propagation model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, homogeneous-equation

$$ \begin{aligned} I' &= -bkIS \\ S' &= bkIS - akS(S+R) \\ R' &= akS(S+R) \end{aligned} $$

where $I'=S'=R'=0$. The inspection of equation system indicates that equilibrium stated are only possible if $S=0$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $S$ and $R$ are nonnegative, yes. You get $R'=0$ only if $S=0$ or $S+R=0$. If you allow $S$ or $R$ to be negative, then there are also equilibria with $I=0, S=-R$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i still dont understand for the last statement.

Comment: For any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the point $S=c,I=0,R=-c$ is a stationary point.